# multiple versions handling in scalaxb

Tags: xml, scala, xsd, scalaxb

I have different versions of a XSD using the same namespace. They differ by the version attribute:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://mynamespace/2014" version="1.3.0">
<xs:schema xmlns="http://mynamespace/2014" version="2.0.0">
```

How to handle different XSD versions with scalaxb in sbt? How to have one package per version?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is multiple configs: http://scalaxb.org/multiple-configs. Thanks eugene from scalaxb for providing this answer and updating the tutorial!